# Setting a variable from a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I was wondering if there is anyway to set a variable from a function. Let me explain with the following code:

```
number = 0
print number

def number_parse():
    number = number + 1
    return number

print number
number_parse()
print number
number = number_parse()
print number
```

I get the following output:

```
0
0
0
1
```

So what I am really trying to ask is, is there a way to set a variable from a function without having to call it from the line:

```
number = number_parse()
```

Can I not define a variable's value just by calling the function? What if I would like to set multiple variables (e.g. number, number_2, number_3 etc)

I am new to python and can't seem to figure this one out

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `global` keyword.

```
number = 0
print number

def number_parse():
    global number
    number = number + 1
    return number

print number
number_parse()
print number
```

Remember it's a bad attitude and you generally should not use it.

You can read more about it here: http://blog.adku.com/2011/11/scope-and-variable-binding-in-python-1.html

Shortly, the rules are:

- Can read from current / higher scope.
- Can't write to higher scope.
- Can't read from higher scope, than write to the current scope new variable with the same name.

That's about it.